# Rename the first instance of a cell one thing but then the next another?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that renames cells in a column based on their value. The cells are alternating so there are multiple instances of the cell that I want to rename.

For example..

The column of data may look like this (before and after):

```
Before           After
---------        ---------
Product 1        Product 1
Product 2        Product 1
Product 3        Cat
Product 3        Dog
Product 4        Product 4
```

As the macro is to rename the cells contents based on their value. I can not simply write a macro to rename Product 3 => Cat as it will rename both cells to Cat. I want the second Product 3 to be Dog.

My product list is then repeated another 4 or 5 times so this macro needs to run in an alternative loop.

Comment: Your description of what you want to acheive isn't clear. It would help to show an actual before --> after example.

Comment: Before:

Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Product 3
Product 4
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Product 3
Product 4

After:

This
That
Else 1
Else 2
Something
This
That
Else 1
Else 2
Something

Comment: That's even less clear!  You can edit your question and add a formatted example. What's "This"? just the word "This"? what decides what each "Product *" becomes?

Comment: Done - sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I fixed your question to provide a better view of the before/after, but it's still not clear how your Product3 renaming works. Is there a fixed list of substitutions, and where is it stored? Does it keep looping around through the replacements? (what would a third Product3 be replaced with?)

Comment: Do you *always* want the first instance of "Product 3" to be replaced by "Cat" and the second by "Dog"? I don't think anyone understands what it is you're trying to accomplish. Pretend this is someone else's question and you're reading it for the first time. Would you understand? Try rewriting your question from that perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with worksheet functions.  Either fill this formula down in an adjacent column, or overwrite your list of product names.

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(ROW()-1,5)+1,"This","That","Else 1","Else 2","Something")
```

This assumes your list starts in Row 1 and repeats in the same manner. If for instance, your list starts in Row 2 instead, just adjust the order of the new name arguments in the formula.  For example, if the list starts in Row 2, use the following instead:

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(ROW()-1,5)+1,"Something","This","That","Else 1","Else 2")
```